# Does docker containers picks the time and timezone from the host machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I've read numerous resources in the internet which doesn't indicate this clearly. Can someone clarify whether docker containers picks the time and timezone from the host machine on startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual time is shared with the host if Docker is running directly on the host.  If you're using a VM-based solution (Docker Machine, Docker Toolbox, Docker Desktop for Mac) the VM has its own time, but all containers running in the VM will share that time.

The time zone is specified by the `TZ` environment variable or an `/etc/localtime` file.  Environment variables are specific per-process, and containers have their own filesystems, which means time zones could be different per container.  If my host believes it is currently 06:02-04:00, a container could very readily believe it's 10:02+00:00.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. Not unless you synchronize both of them or unless, "coincidentally", timezone is same in both docker image and host. In latter case you may feel it's picking timezone from host but it doesn't. However, you can synchronize the timezone with host depending on your base OS in docker container.